# Convert Dart String to dartffi Pointer<Int8>

Tags: c, flutter, dart, dart-ffi

I used [ffigen](https://pub.dev/packages/ffigen) to generate bindings from a C header file.
One of the methods in C is `open(const char *path)`, and ffigen generated a binding method `open(ffi.Pointer<ffi.Int8> path)`.
If I want to have a dart method `open(String path)` that access this binding method how can I convert the String parameter to ffi.Pointer<ffi.Int8>?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
"Your message".toNativeUtf8().cast<Int8>()
```

Also see erjo's comment in https://github.com/dart-lang/ffigen/issues/72